# Basic Authentication from url in Restlet

Tags: java, authentication, restlet, basic-authentication, url-encoding

I've been using Restlets "ChallengeResponse" mechanism to authenticate users on the server side.

```
ChallengeResponse challengeResponse = getRequest().getChallengeResponse();
if( challengeResponse == null ){
     throw new RuntimeException("not authenticated");
}
String login = challengeResponse.getIdentifier();
String password = new String(challengeResponse.getSecret());
```

From my understanding, "ChallengeResponse" requires that the username and password are put into headers.  However a client needs to put the credentials into the url like so:

```
https://username:password@www.myserver.com/my_secure_document
```

When I looked at what was actually sent, it looks like the password is being Base64 encoded

The client is an external web service (Twilio) who sends the authentication information via the URL instead of the headers....

What is the proper way to authenticate in this fashion using Restlet?

Answer (score 2):

The code fragment you've put above looks like it's on the server side.

I presume your question is about using this URI from the client (and I also presume your client uses Restlet). You can build a reference and extract the username and password using Reference.getUserInfo() like this:

```
Reference ref = new Reference("https://username:password@www.myserver.com/my_secure_document");
String[] userinfo = ref.getUserInfo().split(":"); // "username:password"
String username = userinfo[0];
String password = userinfo[1];
ClientResource clientRes = new ClientResource(ref);
clientRes.setChallengeResponse(ChallengeScheme.HTTP_BASIC, username, password);
clientRes.get();
```

(Of course, you'll need to test whether the user info is null before splitting.)

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have been more specific.  The code is on the server side, but the client is an external web service (Twilio) who sends the authentication information via the URL instead of the headers.

Comment: Ah OK. In that case, it doesn't actually send in via the URL, it's just a notation. The client will automatically put this into the headers.

To clarify, just like getting http://example.com/test sends this in fact:
   GET /test HTTP/1.1
   Host: example.com

The username:password are also automatically transformed into the appropriate HTTP headers, when appropriate (as I said on the Restlet list, this is disabled with some browsers for security reasons). The behaviour in this case is purely controlled by the client. It might be worth logging the full requests to see what it sends.

Comment: Since a password may itself contain a colon, consider `ref.getUserInfo().split(":", 2)` (it wasn’t my idea, it was suggested in an edit, I just thought it was the wrong place for it).